# What all parameters we provide for method removeApiAuthenticationKey?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have written code to grant api key access in Softayer using python.But now I want to remove api access. What all parameters we provide for method removeApiAuthenticationKey?

Answer (score 0):

See documentation

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_user_customer/removeapiauthenticationkey

you only need to send the id of the  API authentication key. You can call the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_user_customer/getapiauthenticationkeys to get the id of the API key.

Answer (score 0):

It was still not obvious to me how to correctly pass the parameter keyId to use the removeApiAuthenticationKey REST api.

This article helped:
https://softlayer.github.io/article/rest/

-d '{"parameters": [yourKeyId]}'